# Safari push notification click event handle

Tags: javascript, ruby, safari, apple-push-notifications

I am worked on **web push notification** functionality in safari like chrome and firefox does.

I have use [apnotic](https://github.com/ostinelli/apnotic) and [web-push-notification-rails](https://github.com/ankurp/Apple-Web-Push-Notification-Rails) gem for send push notification and it successfully receive.

However I would get how many click perform on notification?

Comment: Hi, how did you manage to get a click event on safari?